# How to download image from a url provided in php

Tags: php

I have an xml feed that has some image urls provided in it . Each link contains one Images only,

I have to parse this url and download those images in some folder using PHP.

Something like this

```
while($xmlcontent = mysql_fetch_array($images)){

                         download_img($xmlcontent["tag"]);
                }
function download_img($im_url)
{


}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try to use copy() function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download Image URL - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537839/download-image-url-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download File to server from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url)

Answer (score 2):

Put this line in an htaccess file in the directory you want the setting to be enabled:

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

then create a function as simple as this.

```
function download_file($file_url, $save_to)
{
    $content = file_get_contents($file_url);
    file_put_contents($save_to, $content);
}
```

usage:

```
download_file('http://example.com/images/logo.jpg', realpath("./downloads") . '/yourfile.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the URL can be anywhere? Try this:

```
$image = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($filename,$image);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

And yes, `copy()` should also work if you believe that page.

Comment: i tried this i used a folder in the current directory like this  `$newFilePath = './server';
$data = file_get_contents($file);

file_put_contents($newFilePath,$data);` But it says permission denied

Comment: try: `$newFilePath = 'test';` and make sure you've got write permission in the current directory. See: CHMOD (in Linux: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).